# Can't get hitTestObject to tell where player is

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

here's the scenario.

I have a 700px x 700px area for my game. This area is split into triangular quadrants which are added by code in my main game.as. My aim is to get my enemies to spawn in different locations depending on which quadrant the player is in however I can't get the triangles or ship to output anything with the trace function.

I've tried a function similar to this in my main game.as

```
function hitBottom(e:Event)
{
    if(ship.hitTestObject(Tri_Bottom));
    {
     trace("hitBottom")
```

and this one in my ship.as

```
function hitBottom(e:Event)
{
    if(this.hitTestObject(Tri_Bottom));
    {
     trace("hitBottom")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an event listener or a print statement in the hitBottom function before hittest. The code might not be running.

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitBottem);

Also keep in mind hitTestObject is for collision detection on screen - this means Tri_Bottem has to be an object already on screen.

Comment: Most likely those tris are not on the stage, this way they're off the coordinate system, thus `globalToLocal()` returns garbage, which makes `hitTestObject()` return sure false. +1